# MySQL statement works in workbench but errors in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The following sql code runs just fine in MySQL Workbench but returns

> "string(228) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'SELECT p2.this_year,year(p.PAID_DATE) as
>   current_year,c1.s1,c2.p1,c3.p2,ly.last_' at line 6" in PHP.

I've searched for an answer to no avail. Wondering if anyone has any ideas. Thanks in advance.

```
$dbinfo = dbinfo();
$con = mysqli_connect($dbinfo['localhost'],$dbinfo['localuser'],$dbinfo['localpass'],$dbase);
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));

$sql = "
SET @startdate = DATE(CURDATE()- INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())+1 DAY), @enddate = CURDATE(),
    @laststart = DATE_SUB(@startdate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
    @lastend = DATE_SUB(@enddate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    ;

SELECT p2.this_year,year(p.PAID_DATE) as current_year,c1.s1,c2.p1,c3.p2,ly.last_year,
    lyc1.s1,lyc2.p1,lyc3.p2
FROM btb.payments as p

join (
    select CLIENTID,sum(TOTAL) this_year,PAID_DATE
    from btb.payments
    where PAID_DATE between @startdate and @enddate
) as p2

join (
    select id_no,count(SUMMER_PT1) S1 
    from btb.Client
    where SUMMER_PT1 <> ''
) as c1
    on c1.ID_NO = p.CLIENTID

join (
    select id_no,count(PART1) P1
    from btb.Client
    where PART1 <> ''
) as c2

join (
    select id_no,count(PART2) P2
    from btb.Client
    where PART2 <> ''
) as c3

join (
    SELECT CLIENTID,sum(TOTAL) as last_year
    FROM btb.payments
    where PAID_DATE between @laststart and @lastend
) as ly

join (
SELECT d.CLIENTID,d.SESSION,count(p.CLIENTID) s1
FROM btb.Details d
join btb.payments p
    on p.CLIENTID = d.CLIENTID
where p.PAID_DATE between @laststart and @lastend
    and d.year = year(@laststart)
    and d.SESSION = 'S1'
) as lyc1
    -- on c1.ID_NO = p.CLIENTID

join (
SELECT d.CLIENTID,d.SESSION,count(p.CLIENTID) p1
FROM btb.Details d
join btb.payments p
    on p.CLIENTID = d.CLIENTID
where p.PAID_DATE between @laststart and @lastend
    and d.year = year(@laststart)
    and d.SESSION = 'P1'
) as lyc2

join (
SELECT d.CLIENTID,d.SESSION,count(p.CLIENTID) p2
FROM btb.Details d
join btb.payments p
    on p.CLIENTID = d.CLIENTID
where p.PAID_DATE between @laststart and @lastend
    and d.year = year(@laststart)
    and d.SESSION = 'P2'
) as lyc3

where p.PAID_DATE between @startdate and @enddate
;";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($result === false) {
    var_dump(mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
    print_r(mysqli_num_rows($result));
}
```

Comment: Does this really has anything to do with PHP? Looks like your code contains only SQL..

Comment: Sorry, have edited and added the PHP code as well.

Comment: Are you allowed to use multiple sql statements in one `mysqli` query? I would try a simple  'set'  and a simple query in the same query.

Comment: I took out the set statement and replaced with the variables in the MySQL statement with PHP variables and it works now. I'll post the solution code. Thanks a million Ryan!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that more than one sql statement in a mysqli_query doesn't work so I change the code as follows and voila!

```
    $dbase = "btb";

$dbinfo = dbinfo();
$con = mysqli_connect($dbinfo['localhost'],$dbinfo['localuser'],$dbinfo['localpass'],$dbase);
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
$startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('01/01'));
$enddate = date("Y-m-d");
$startlast = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startdate . ' -1 year'));
$endlast = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($enddate . ' -1 year'));

echo "$startdate - $enddate = $startlast = $endlast";

$sql = "
SELECT 
    p2.this_year,year(p.PAID_DATE) as current_year,c1.s1,c2.p1,c3.p2,ly.last_year,
    lyc1.s1 as ly_s1,lyc2.p1 as ly_p1,lyc3.p2 as ly_p2

FROM $dbase.payments p

join (
    select CLIENTID,sum(TOTAL) this_year,PAID_DATE
    from $dbase.payments
    where PAID_DATE between '$startdate' and '$enddate'
) as p2

join (
    select id_no,count(SUMMER_PT1) S1 
    from $dbase.Client
    where SUMMER_PT1 <> ''
) as c1
    on c1.ID_NO = p.CLIENTID

join (
    select id_no,count(PART1) P1
    from $dbase.Client
    where PART1 <> ''
) as c2

join (
    select id_no,count(PART2) P2
    from $dbase.Client
    where PART2 <> ''
) as c3

join (
    SELECT CLIENTID,sum(TOTAL) as last_year
    FROM $dbase.payments
    where PAID_DATE between '$startlast' and '$endlast'
) as ly

join (
SELECT d.CLIENTID,d.SESSION,count(p.CLIENTID) s1
FROM $dbase.Details d
join $dbase.payments p
    on p.CLIENTID = d.CLIENTID
where p.PAID_DATE between '$startlast' and '$endlast'
    and d.year = year('$startlast')
    and d.SESSION = 'S1'
) as lyc1

join (
SELECT d.CLIENTID,d.SESSION,count(p.CLIENTID) p1
FROM $dbase.Details d
join $dbase.payments p
    on p.CLIENTID = d.CLIENTID
where p.PAID_DATE between '$startlast' and '$endlast'
    and d.year = year('$startlast')
    and d.SESSION = 'P1'
) as lyc2

join (
SELECT d.CLIENTID,d.SESSION,count(p.CLIENTID) p2
FROM $dbase.Details d
join $dbase.payments p
    on p.CLIENTID = d.CLIENTID
where p.PAID_DATE between '$startlast' and '$endlast'
    and d.year = year('$startlast')
    and d.SESSION = 'P2'
) as lyc3

where p.PAID_DATE between '$startdate' and '$enddate'
;";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //print_r($row);
    $this_year = $row['this_year'];
    $year = $row['current-year'];
    $this_s1 = $row['s1'];
    $this_p1 = $row['p1'];
    $this_p2 = $row['p2'];
    $last_year = $row['last_year'];
    $last_s1 = $row['ly_s1'];
    $last_p1 = $row['ly_p1'];
    $last_p2 = $row['ly_p2'];
}
```